# Popups with promotion

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, malware, popup

Sometimes, I'm getting popups on my Samsung S8 with promotions. Especially it is annoying during navigation with Google Maps. How to disable popups? How to know which application is responsible on that? 
[image]

Comment: what is Izzy's list and where I can find it?

Comment: @vico Izzy is me, and the list beeshyams was pointing at is here: [Ad-Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker). If your device is rooted I recommend AdAway; if not, the [firewall](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall) app Netguard [can also block ads](https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard/blob/master/ADBLOCKING.md). To find out which app is causing the popup, see e.g. [Got stuck with a Pop-up on the main screen](/q/137854/16575) and the questions linked to it.

Comment: @izzy thanks for filling in. I thought I posted the link. Growing old and forgetful. Sorry Vico